# Set Dropdown value based on Browser Language ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i have a small setup in which i have a dropdown and the Dropdown has two values. I am trying to set the default value of the dropdown based on the browser language detected. So if the Browser language is English, the dropdown and it's value should default to `English` and if the Language is `Spanish` then it should default to Spanish and so on. Essentially it should be dynamic and it might grow more into the Future. Any help will be Appreciated.

Check out this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-cori-wudl3?file=/src/App.js) for a working example.

This is the complete Code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Newbie extends Component {
  state = {
    languageSelection: [
      { option: "English", value: "en-us" },
      { option: "Spanish", value: "es" }
    ]
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    let detectedLanguage = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    alert("The Language is " + detectedLanguage)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          Language
          <select>
            <option value="en-us">English</option>
            <option value="es">Spanish</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Newbie;
```

Thank you for all the assistance guys!! Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Newbie extends Component {
  state = { selected: navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selected: e.target.value })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          Language
          <select value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="en-US">English</option>
            <option value="es">Spanish</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Newbie;
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Accepting it as soon as the timer ends!!